# when use in 2.0, i got the error,Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

please help me to convert the coding...

```
Public Sub FillListView(ByVal lstbox As ListView, ByVal colwidth As Integer, ByVal dset As DataSet)
    Dim c As DataColumn
    For Each c In dset.Tables(0).Columns
        Dim h As New ColumnHeader
        h.Text = c.ColumnName
        h.Width = colwidth
        ' lstbox.Invoke(
        lstbox.Columns.Add(h) ''Problem here
        ') 
    Next

    Dim dt As DataTable = dset.Tables(0)
    Dim str(dset.Tables(0).Columns.Count) As String

    Dim rr As DataRow
    For Each rr In dt.Rows
        For col As Integer = 0 To dset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            str(col) = rr(col).ToString()
        Next
        Dim ii As New ListViewItem(str)
        lstbox.Items.Add(ii) ''Problem here
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to show the context of how you are calling FillListView

Comment: If count_row > 0 Then
                    If ds_xml.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString <> "" Then
                        Dim lengthSize As Integer = ListView1.Size.Width / 3 - 2
                        ListView1.Clear()
                        FillListView(ListView1, lengthSize, ds_xml)
                    End If
                    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).EnsureVisible()
                End If                                                                                                          THis path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you must be calling this from a thread other than the UI thread.  In order to fix it, you need to invoke back to the UI thread.  Here's one way you could do it:

```
Public Delegate Sub FillListView(ByVal lstbox As ListView, ByVal colwidth As Integer, ByVal dset As DataSet)

Public Sub FillListView(ByVal lstbox As ListView, ByVal colwidth As Integer, ByVal dset As DataSet)

    ' Invoke back to the UI thread, if necessary
    If lstbox.InvokeRequired Then
        lstbox.Invoke(New FillListViewDelegate(AddressOf FillListView), listbox, colWidth, dset))
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim c As DataColumn
    For Each c In dset.Tables(0).Columns
        Dim h As New ColumnHeader
        h.Text = c.ColumnName
        h.Width = colwidth
        lstbox.Columns.Add(h)
    Next

    Dim dt As DataTable = dset.Tables(0)
    Dim str(dset.Tables(0).Columns.Count) As String

    Dim rr As DataRow
    For Each rr In dt.Rows
        For col As Integer = 0 To dset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            str(col) = rr(col).ToString()
        Next
        Dim ii As New ListViewItem(str)
        lstbox.Items.Add(ii)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: hi steven,                                                                                                                  If lstbox.InvokeRequired Then
            lstbox.Invoke(Sub() FillListView(lstbox, colwidth, dset))
            Exit Sub
        End If                                                                                                                  question: what expression expected at Sub()  ?

Comment: Ah, right.  Sorry.  You're in .NET 2.0, so no lambdas.  Without lambda's, you'll need to declare a custom delegate which matches your method.  I've updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: steven, hi, i want to ask, 
how to create function search from .xml file. i want to search use "likes" from data in .xml file. 
please help..
.

Comment: Sounds like a new question. I'm not sure what you mean by "likes", but XPath or LINQ-to-XML may very well provide what you need. If not, you may need to combine one of those techniques with regex.

Comment: like means, i want to use like operator..  actually,the situation like this, i want create button search, and user can search the folder by 'title' in .xml file.

Comment: That is easy to do with either XPath or LINQ-to-XML

Comment: sir, you have example for i to refer. i dont know how to search ...tq sir

Comment: The Internet is rife with examples. Providing tutorials is not the purpose StackOverflow. If you have a specific question, ask it as a new question. I hope I'm not coming across as rude, it's just the way this site works.